# In Ansible playbooks how can i set a variable depending on inventory_hostname filtering matching a list of predefined values?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I'm trying to assign a variable in my playbook for later use based on hostname:

(without revealing actual hostnames)

- ...p........001
- ...s........001
- ...t........001
- etc...

and a list to assign depending on the 4th letter from the hostname

- Production
- Staging
- Test
- etc...

based on the 4th letter in the hostname, I want to set **myvar** per hostname which I run this playbook against:

- if p, **myvar** = Production
- if s, **myvar** = Staging
- if t, **myvar** = Test

I have tried, and decided that the 4th letter can be captured from the hostname as so:

inventory_hostname[3]

This method seems to work:

```
  - name: Some task
    set_fact:
      **myvar**: Production
    when: inventory_hostname[3] == "p"

  - name: Some task 2
    set_fact:
      **myvar**: Staging
    when: inventory_hostname[3] == "s"

  - name: Some task 3
    set_fact:
      **myvar**: Test
    when: inventory_hostname[3] == "t"

  - name: Content of myvar?
    debug:
      msg: "{{ myvar }}"
    when: myvar is defined
```

The output is as follows, which appears to work:

```
TASK [Prod environment?] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [...p........001]
    
TASK [Stage environment?] ********************************************************************************************
skipping: [...p........001]
    
TASK [Test environment?] ********************************************************************************************
skipping: [...p........001]
    
TASK [Content of myvar?] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [...p........001] => {
        "msg": "Production"
    }
```

I assume the solution might be a single task which literally translates to something like:

```
- name: Some task
  set_fact:
    **myvar**: if inventory_hostname[3] == p or s or t and this exists in {{ varfile }} set Production or Staging or Test
```

I want to either:

1. Reduce the number of tasks required to work this variable out by
   either doing a "loop and replace" based on the 4th character match,
   but I cant figure out the best way to do this within a playbook.
2. Accept a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary *myvar_dict*, declare *myvar* and put it into the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/myvar.yml
myvar_dict:
  p: Production
  s: Staging
  t: Test
  default: Sales
myvar: "{{ myvar_dict[inventory_hostname.3]|default(myvar_dict.default) }}"
```

Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
001production
001staging
001test
007business
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: myvar
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************
ok: [001production] => 
  myvar: Production
ok: [001staging] => 
  myvar: Staging
ok: [001test] => 
  myvar: Test
ok: [007business] => 
  myvar: Sales
```

---

**Create the dictionary from the list**

Given the list

```yaml
  myvar_list: [Production, Staging, Test]
```

declare the default and create a dictionary

```yaml
  myvar_default: {default: Sales}
  myvar_dict: "{{ dict(myvar_list|map('first')|map('lower')|
                       zip(myvar_list))|
                  combine(myvar_default) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  myvar_dict:
    default: Sales
    p: Production
    s: Staging
    t: Test
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    myvar_list: [Production, Staging, Test]

    myvar_default: {default: Sales}
    myvar_dict: "{{ dict(myvar_list|map('first')|map('lower')|
                         zip(myvar_list))|
                    combine(myvar_default) }}"

    myvar: "{{ myvar_dict[inventory_hostname.3]|default(myvar_dict.default) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: myvar_dict
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: myvar
```

Comment: This works! Does it have to be in separate files or can I put this into the vars of the playbook?

Comment: Yes. You can, of course. If you want to have it there.

Comment: Put the link here. Delete the comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75724516/how-to-set-a-variable-depending-on-inventory-hostname-filtering-matching-a-dicti