# How do I set a variable depending on inventory_hostname filtering matching a dictionary in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, yaml, formatting

I already asked and received an answer to a similar question here:
[In Ansible playbooks how can i set a variable depending on inventory_hostname filtering matching a list of predefined values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251432/in-ansible-playbooks-how-can-i-set-a-variable-depending-on-inventory-hostname-fi)

I now face a confusing issue trying to do the same thing but with different values.

From the previous issue:

I created a playbook (SCRIPT1.yml) which matches the value in the dict and puts it into a variable based on the 4th letter in inventory_hostname. this was the var_file i used in this script.

environmentlist.yml

```yaml
myvar_dict:
  p: Production
  s: Staging
  t: Test
  default: Sales
myvar: "{{ myvar_dict[inventory_hostname.3]|default(myvar_dict.default) }}"
```

The new confusing part, SCRIPT2.yml:

otherlist.yml:

```yaml
myvar2_dict:
  S: VALUE1
  1: VALUE2
  2: VALUE3
  3: VALUE4
  4: VALUE5
  5: VALUE6
  default: VALUE1
myvar2: "{{ myvar2_dict[inventory_hostname.8]|default(myvar2_dict.default) }}"
```

my hosts are:

```
000p00002hostname
000t0000Shostname
000s00005hostname
```

I then have a larger playbook which imports both of these separately.

So, they each have their own dicts and each set a new variable but I cannot use "myvar" in SCRIPT2.yml for example.

Also, when my playbook reaches the imported play (SCRIPT2.yml) where it tries to set "myvar2", it DOES display the correct value from the hostname (e.g. "2") but then errors that there is no dict_value for that, so i'm not sure what I am missing.

I have a suspicion that i may need to import the variable from SCRIPT1.yml to SCRIPT2.yml
OR import both myvar and myvar2 from these plays into the playbook which imports them, but i'm not sure how best to structure the code.

I have tried the following:

After some research, I think it may be an issue that i am importing playbooks and the variables are not sticking between plays.

Removing the lines which actually set the variables outside of the yaml list files and into the scripts, but have not had luck defining the variables this way.

e.g.

`myvar: "{{ myvar_dict[inventory_hostname.3]|default(myvar_dict.default) }}"`

...was placed into the SCRIPT1.yml script, while;

`myvar2: "{{ myvar2_dict[inventory_hostname.8]|default(myvar2_dict.default) }}"`

...was placed into the SCRIPT2.yml script.

I would like to be able to use these to create a new variable too, so its important to be able to do this correctly.

Example of what I would like to do later once this works:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Determine the correct Spacewalk group for this server
    set_fact:
      MYGROUPVAR: "{{ myvar }} {{ myvar2 }}"`

  - name: run some script
    script: script.py "{{ inventory_hostname }}" "{{ MYGROUPVAR }}"
```

(forgive me if I don't share the actual yml scripts here due to potentially sensitive info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that the keys in your new `myvar2_dict` are a mix of integers and strings while `inventory_hostname.X` systematically returns a string. Hence, as is, `myvar2_dict[1]` does not exist (and will return the default value) while `myvar2_dict["1"]` does exist with its corresponding value (`VALUE2`)

There are basically 2 ways to fix this problem: cast your data to int prior to accessing the integer dict key (not ideal with a mix as in your example), or define all keys as strings from start. I demonstrated the second option in the below example.

Moreover, your environment seems extremely complicated when you can define all of the above in your inventory and use it anywhere. Here is a full example just to show you the way to something much more maintainable.

Test file structure:

```
.
├── inventories
│   └── demo
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all.yml
│       └── hosts.yml
└── playbook.yml
```

`inventories/demo/hosts.yml`

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    000p00002hostname:
    000t0000Shostname:
    000s00005hostname:
```

`inventories/demo/group_vars/all.yml`

```yaml
---
myvar_dict:
  p: Production
  s: Staging
  t: Test
  default: Sales
myvar: "{{ myvar_dict[inventory_hostname.3] | default(myvar_dict.default) }}"
# Make sure all keys are strings so you don't have
# to later convert from your inventory_name substring
myvar2_dict:
  S: VALUE1
  "1": VALUE2
  "2": VALUE3
  "3": VALUE4
  "4": VALUE5
  "5": VALUE6
  default: VALUE1
myvar2: "{{ myvar2_dict[inventory_hostname.8] | default(myvar2_dict.default) }}"
```

`playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: display our vars
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg:
          - 4th letter is {{ inventory_hostname.3 }}
          - 9th letter is {{ inventory_hostname.8 }}
          - myvar is {{ myvar }}
          - myvar2 is {{ myvar2 }}
```

Running the playbook against the demo inventory gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/demo/ playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [display our vars] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [000t0000Shostname] => {
    "msg": [
        "4th letter is t",
        "9th letter is S",
        "myvar is Test",
        "myvar2 is VALUE1"
    ]
}
ok: [000s00005hostname] => {
    "msg": [
        "4th letter is s",
        "9th letter is 5",
        "myvar is Staging",
        "myvar2 is VALUE6"
    ]
}
ok: [000p00002hostname] => {
    "msg": [
        "4th letter is p",
        "9th letter is 2",
        "myvar is Production",
        "myvar2 is VALUE3"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
000p00002hostname          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
000s00005hostname          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
000t0000Shostname          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```